# Find an Object in an array by comparing Object->value to all Object->values in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

So my array contains objects like this:

```
$arr = array(
    new Card('10', 'Spades'),
    new Card('Jack', 'Diamonds'),
    new Card('King', 'Spades')
);
```

Now I have a function:

```
function hasCard(Card $card) {
    if (in_array($card, $arr)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now above does not really work since I need to compare `($card->rank == $arr[$x]->rank)` for each element in that `$arr` without looping. Is there a function on PHP that allows you to modify the compareTo method of array_search?

Comment: If you insist on using plain English in your arrays, you should probably have an associated array that holds the values.  You only need that plain English to show the user anyway.  And you're creating a seperate step at processing time.

Comment: @durbnpoisn there are more other values associated to each Card object so no I can not really use regular arrays, I need it to be an object.

Comment: Try [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter).  You can pass that a function to compare the `rank`s.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Would you mind showing an example? As far as I know array_filter filters out array elements that return false

Comment: @GGio: Exactly!  So, filter out elements that *don't* match the rank.  Then check how many elements remain.  If that's more than 0, then it's in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) here.  (Note: make sure `$arr` is available inside the `hasCard` function)

```
function hasCard(Card $card) {
    $inArray = array_filter($arr, function($x) use($card){
        return $x->rank === $card->rank;
    });

    return count($inArray) > 0;
}
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/166460

Answer (score 1):

The `$arr` variable is not going to be available within the function `hasCard`, unless you pass it as a parameter.

To answer your question, look at [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). This will get you a callable function in which you can pass the `$arr` and `$card` as parameters.